# Why is data disappearing from an Oracle Spatial database with an MS Access front end?

Tags: ms-access, oracle-spatial

I use an Oracle Spatial database with an MS Access front end and recently data fields have started to disappear. When I output a summary of the records names have been disappearing that were in the previous summary. It is an older system that I did not build so I don't know what is going on in the back end. What could be the reason for this? The system is about 8 years old and this problem has only popped up recently.

I haven't done any testing or playing about in the background as I am unfamiliar with MS Access and I don't want to risk doing more damage.

Comment: Fields are gone or data missing from field? This is not a programming issue so question not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Some fields within certain entries are missing. If the question isn't really a SO one can you suggest a more appropriate site?

Comment: One is AccessForums.net. "Some fields within certain entries are missing" doesn't make sense. Fields don't come and go for each record. Data might not be there but the fields should be.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take my query across to there.

Comment: As already said, this requires some concrete evidence if you want any help. BTW there is no such thing as an "Oracle Spatial" database. Oracle databases can store all sorts of data: numbers, dates, strings, geometries, images, documents, json, XML, ... I doubt that the presence of columns with geometry types is a factor here. But again, checking that tables with geometry column(s) exhibit the error while others (without such columns) don't would be a good start. Version numbers would be helpful too.

Comment: Cheers, Albert. I'll look into that.